# Best practice for passing Pandas DataFrame to functions

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, mutable

I am currently working with a few DataFrames and want to make my code modular. That entails passing DataFrames to functions. I am aware of the mutable nature of DataFrames and some of the 'gotchas' when passing mutable instances to functions. Is there a best practice for DataFrames to the functions? Should I make a copy within the function and then pass it back? Or should I just make changes to df within the function and return None?

Is option 1 or 2 better? Below is basic code to convey the idea:

Option 1:

```
def test(df):
    df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
    return None

test(df)
```

Option 2:

```
def test(main_df):
    df = main_df.copy()
    df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
    return df 

main_df = test(main_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a lot of `DataFrame.pipe` to organize my code so, I'm going to say option 2. `pipe` takes and returns a DataFrame and you can chain multiple steps together.

```py
def step1(main_df):
    df = main_df.copy()
    df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
    return df 

def step2(main_df):
    df = main_df.copy()
    df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
    return df 

def setp3(main_df):
    df = main_df.copy()
    df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
    return df 

main_df = (main_df.pipe(step1)
    .pipe(step2)
    .pipe(step3)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think *Option 1* is bad way. Why? Because is [not Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (side effects on mutable reference arguments).

How to google for details: `pure` / `deterministic` / `nondeterministic` functions.

So I think the second way is better.

Comment: Is option 2 a best practice for working with dataframes and passing them to functions, or is there a better way I should be aware of.

Comment: @Boom not sure if you really need to `copy df` in every function. yes, you can do it if you really need a new [dataframe](https://prnt.sc/xsr9eo)